# PayPal IPN script does not work with donator express

Tags: php, express, paypal, paypal-ipn

I was trying to use the DonatorExpress IPN script but it always give me th error 500...

```
include('ipnlistener.php');        
if ($verified) {
    $errmsg = '';
        if ($_POST['payment_status'] != 'Completed') {
            exit(0);
        }
        if ($_POST['receiver_email'] != $paypal) {
            $errmsg .= "'receiver_email' does not match: ";
            $errmsg .= $_POST['receiver_email']."\n";
        }
        if ($_POST['mc_currency'] != $currency_code) {
            $errmsg .= "'mc_currency' does not match: ";
            $errmsg .= $_POST['mc_currency']."\n";
        }
        if (empty($errmsg)) {
        $useremail = $_POST['item_number'];
        error_log($useremail);
        $gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        error_log($gross);
        $newtoken = $_POST['custom'];
        $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
        $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
        $payeremail = $_POST['payer_email'];
```

My ipn scripts: 
http://pastebin.com/4kx7ZgpM 
http://pastebin.com/zqFF1SfV
IIS log:

```
2015-03-10 16:07:02 148.***.***.14 POST /donate/ipn.php - 80 - 173.0.81.1 PayPal+IPN+(+https://www.paypal.com/ipn+) - 303 0 0 161
2015-03-10 16:07:02 148.***.***.14 GET /donate/ipn.php - 443 - 173.0.81.1 PayPal+IPN+(+https://www.paypal.com/ipn+) - 500 0 0 201
```

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your script in the body of your question.

Comment: dont you think its to long? is there any sort ofe code block?

Comment: Select the relevant parts and provide a link for what remains. And yes the editor provide a way to format code block.

Comment: i am not sure but i think this is the most important